# Iterate over array in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I have an array in MIPS, and I'm trying to iterate over it.

This code works when I want to get the value of a specific array cell, but it throws a Runtime with `address out of range 0x10565554` when I try to loop through it.

```
.data
boardState: .word 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,        
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,        
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,        
        9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,        
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,        
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,        
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,        
        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,        
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0         
.text

main:
    la $t3, boardState
    li $t2, 0
    li $t4, 63
    jal loop

loop:
    add $t2, $t2, $t2
    add $t2, $t2, $t2 #quadruple index
    add $t1, $t2, $t3 #add index/offset to array address

    lw $a0, 0($t1) #load word into $a0 ***this is where it throws the error***
    li $v0, 1      #load syscall for printing integer
    syscall

    beq $t2, $t4, exit #branches to a syscall 10 if array length is reached
    addi $t2, $t2, 1   #else iterates and jumps back to loop beginning
    j loop
```

I have a branch under this called `single` that doesn't use a loop, but like I said, it uses the same exact code to find the index of the array, and prints it using `syscall` and works perfectly.

I found a code snippet somewhere that used `sll` to increment the index, but I don't really know how to use `sll`. I'm sticking with this code because it works in the single instance.

Comment: The way you update `$t1` now means you'll accumulate all the indexes as you go along. Either change `add $t1, $t2, $t3` to use another register as its destination and then use that register as the address for `lw`, or remove the first three lines of the loop and put an `addi $t1, $t1, 4` right before `j loop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single step through this in the debugger, and you'll see the error.

In the C language, this is roughly what the code is doing:

```
for ( int t2 = 0; t2 != 63; t2++ ) {
    t2 *= 4;
    ...boardState[t2]...;
}
```

So, the loop control variables is being quadrupled and also incremented.

Thus, `$t2` takes on these values: 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 20, 21, 84, 85, 340, 341, 1364, 1365, 5460, 5461, ...

Since the loop exit condition test is using equality (= 63) , and the loop control variable is not going up strictly by 1's, it doesn't hit the loop exit condition, and eventually it will crash attempting to load from memory with a bad address using a very, very large index.

But if you step through the code just 2 iteration's worth, you will be able to spot the problem.

Comment: Yeah I can't believe I didn't notice that. Things like this, man...